Why $h^0(F_n)=\chi(F_n)$ if $n>>0$?
I would like to ask something about sheaf cohomology. I'm very novice at this, so if anyone can explain me in detail or give me some reference, I would appreciate very much!
Let $X$ be an irreducible curve over a field $L$, $P$ a closed point and let
\begin{equation}
F=F_0 \supset F_{-1} \supset ... \supset F_{1-t} \supset F_{-t}=F(-P)
\end{equation}
a maximal flag of coherent $O_X-$modules ($length(F_{n+1}/F_n)=1$).
We can extend this flag to all $n\geq 0$ by requering
\begin{equation}
F_{n+t}=F_n(P)
\end{equation}
for example, $F_1=F_{1-t}(P)$. We see that $F_n \subset F_{n+1}$. Assuming that $\chi(F_0)=0$ we see that $\chi(F_n)=n$ , where $\chi(F_n)= h^0(F_n)-h^1(F_n)$, and $h^i(F_n)=dim_LH^i(X,F_n)$.
As $F_n \subset F_{n+1}$, it is known that $h^1(F_{n})\geq h^1(F_{n+1})$. Why $h^0(F_n)=\chi(F_n)$ if $n>>0$? Any property of the sheaves $F_n$ or the curve $X$ to be this true?

So your question amounts to why $h^1(F_n)=0$ for $n$ large enough, ie why is it impossible that for all $n$ large enough, $h^1(F_n)$ is a positive constant?

@Aphelli Yes! Is property of the sheaves or the curve?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_sheaf_cohomology#Vanishing_theorems

Could you define what a "coherent maximal flag of $\mathcal{O}X$-modules" is? If you can do something silly like just letting $F_n=F{n+1}$, then this result has no chance; otherwise it's probably a consequence of Serre vanishing for sufficiently twisted sheaves.

Hello everybody and thanks for your answers. I think, as @KReiser said, it is a consequence of Serre vanishing. Indeed, the sheaves $F_n$ are twsted by $O_X(P)$, where $P$ is a divisor of $X$ and $length(F_{n+1}/F_n)=1$.

Please write the definition in your post using an [edit] - if you've gotten enough in the comments to resolve the question, please consider writing an answer to your own question to help future people with this issue.
